# Intersection of two data frames with different columns in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Data Science and I am working on a simple self project using Google Colab. I took a data from a `something1.csv` file and `something2.csv` file.

```
df1 = spark.read.csv('something1.csv', header=True)
df2 = spark.read.csv('something2.csv', header=True)
```

The data of `something1.csv` looks like

```
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
#|   country| Latitude| Longitude|   col1 |  col2 |
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
#|   Andorra|   42.506|    1.5218|    2   |   1   |
#| Australia|   -31.81|    115.86|    1   |   6   |
#|   Austria|   41.597|    12.580|    4   |   9   |
#|   Belgium|   21.782|     1.286|    2   |   3   |
#|     India|   78.389|    12.972|    1   |   7   |
#|   Ireland|    9.281|     9.286|    9   |   8   |
#|       USA|   69.371|    21.819|    7   |   2   |
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
```

The data of `something2.csv` looks like

```
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
#|   country| Latitude| Longitude|   col1 |  col2 |
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
#| Australia|   -31.81|    115.86|    2   |   6   |
#|   Belgium|   21.782|     1.286|    1   |   6   |
#|     India|   78.389|    12.972|    3   |   5   |
#|       USA|   69.371|    21.819|    2   |   5   |
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
```

Now I want to intersect df2 with df1 based on `Longitude` and `Latitude` and get the rows that are present in df1 along with col1 and col2 from df1. My table should look like

```
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
#|   country| Latitude| Longitude|   col1 |  col2 |
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
#| Australia|   -31.81|    115.86|    1   |   6   |
#|   Belgium|   21.782|     1.286|    2   |   3   |
#|     India|   78.389|    12.972|    1   |   7   |
#|       USA|   69.371|    21.819|    7   |   2   |
#+----------+---------+----------+--------+-------+
```

I tried using the following code but didn't work.

```
new_df =  df1.intersect(df2) #using the intersection in pyspark which gave me null table
```

Then I also tried based on `Latitude` and `Longitude`

```
new_df = df2.select('Latitude','Longitude').intersect(df1.select('Latitude','Logitude')) #intersecting based on columns
```

I tried both the above methods in pyspark but didn't work.

Comment: Spark Version ?

Comment: @Srinivas Yes spark version and pyspark

Comment: df1.intersect(df2) this will give empty result because you don't have matching rows in both df, which is expected. second one should give result because both columns have matching rows in both dfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Intersect`** only gets rows that are common in both dataframes.

- But in your case you need **`col1,col2`** from `df1` and other columns from `df2`, Join the **dataframes** (left/inner as per requirement) and select only **`col1,col2`** from df1 and other columns from df2.
- (or) As mentioned in comments by [**`Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10107389/mohammad-murtaza-hashmi) Use **`left_semi`** join

**`Example:`**

```
#using left semi join
df1.join(df2,['Latitude','Longitude'],'left_semi').show()

#using left join
df2.alias("t2").join(df1.alias("t1"),['Latitude','Longitude'],'left').select("t2.country","t2.Latitude","t2.Longitude","t1.col1","t1.col2").show()
#+---------+--------+---------+----+----+
#|  country|Latitude|Longitude|col1|col2|
#+---------+--------+---------+----+----+
#|Australia|  -31.81|   115.86|   1|   6|
#|  Belgium|  21.782|    1.286|   2|   3|
#|    India|  78.389|   12.972|   1|   7|
#|      USA|  69.371|   21.819|   7|   2|
#+---------+--------+---------+----+----+
```

---

**`Dynamic way:`**

```
#join columns
join_cols=[x for x in df1.columns if x.startswith("L")]

#selecting cols from t1
t1_cols=["t1."+x for x in df1.columns if x.startswith("col")]

#selecting cols from t2
t2_cols=["t2."+x for x in df2.columns if not x.startswith("col")]

df2.alias("t2").join(df1.alias("t1"),['Latitude','Longitude'],'inner').select(*t2_cols + t1_cols).show()

#+---------+--------+---------+----+----+
#|  country|Latitude|Longitude|col1|col2|
#+---------+--------+---------+----+----+
#|Australia|  -31.81|   115.86|   1|   6|
#|  Belgium|  21.782|    1.286|   2|   3|
#|    India|  78.389|   12.972|   1|   7|
#|      USA|  69.371|   21.819|   7|   2|
#+---------+--------+---------+----+----+
```

Comment: How to do the above joining if I have multiple columns like 50 or more columns?

Comment: @Shu why not use left_semi? `df1.join(df2,['Latitude','Longitude'],'left_semi')`

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi, Sure we can use that too.., Please add as answer..!

Comment: @R0bert, Please check the `updated` answer!, we can create variables based on `df.columns` and use them in join.

Comment: @Shu Thanks for the answer, but my problem is that the column names in the data set are encrypted with ####, So I don't know the column names. I need to get the intersection of the tables only based on the Latitude and Longitude and also get the other 50-100 columns

Comment: @R0bert, did you try `df1.join(df2,['Latitude','Longitude'],'left_semi')` as mentioned in the comments by `Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi`?